# How do I reach the second child node of an element XML in vbscript?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

After spending many hours on the internet I was not able to get this to work and need some help.

XML:

[xml snippet highlighting NoteSynopsis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FK4uE.png)

CODE:

```
set xmlDoc  = SERVER.CREATEOBJECT("MSXML2.DomDocument.6.0")
xmlDoc.async = False              xmlDoc.Load("D:\GVPApplications\TechSupportCreateIncident\CreateIncidentRequest.xml")    
xmlDoc.setProperty "NewParser","true"               

set Root = xmlDoc.documentElement

set NodeList1 = Root.getElementsByTagName("IncidentNote")

                 For Each Elem in NodeList1
                     if Elem.firstChild.nodename = "Note" then
                          Elem.firstChild.text = Notes
                     end if

                 Next
```

ISSUE:
As highlighted in the image XML , I need to be able to read "NoteSynopsis" element and its value. As simple as this seems I have not been able to find a solution to this. If this was the last child no issue, I would do a Elem.LastChild.nodename, but this isn't!

Comment: Are you uploading xml file? i can test my computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `selectSingleNode(...)` method and use XPath

```
set xmlDoc  = SERVER.CREATEOBJECT("MSXML2.DomDocument.6.0")
xmlDoc.async = False              xmlDoc.Load("D:\GVPApplications\TechSupportCreateIncident\CreateIncidentRequest.xml")    
xmlDoc.setProperty "NewParser","true"
xmlDocument.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"               

Dim firstIncidentNote
set firstIncidentNote = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//IncidentNote")
Dim note
Dim noteSynopsis
set note = firstIncidentNote.GetAttribute("Note")
set note = firstIncidentNote.GetAttribute("NoteSynopsis")
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757846(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The issue with SelectSingleNode is it parses the very first value of the Element(in this case IncidentNote). If I have multiple elements IncidentNote how do I get to say the second IncidentNote.

Comment: You could for example write: `xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//IncidentNote")[1]`